# AngularJs, chat application. Dynamic directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am developing a chat application with Angular as a Backbone developer. It is a learning experience and I don't know how to manage this.

In my example there are users and chatting each other like facebook chat app. Click a user and create a room then start chatting very simple. It is very manageable with backbone

```
var room = {
    id: 123123,
    participants: [{
        id: 123,
        name: 'user-1'
    }, {
        id: 124,
        name: 'user-2'
    }]
};

var newChatWindow = new App.views.ChatWindow({
    model: new App.models.Chat(room)
});
```

And with this i can manage multiple chat windows in their own scope.

I figure angular directives can do this. But how create new Controller for every opened room and run in their own scope. I need a good practice.
When separated controllers emit a message like below.

```
SocketService.emit('newMessage', {
  room: room,
  data: {
    message: "bla bla",
    owner: user
        ...
  }
});
```

I need a short example to explain how to manage like this with Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the directive you just specify the controller name.

```
var directive = function() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: 'group.panel.controller',
            templateUrl: '/templates/groups/group_panel'
        };

    };

    module.directive('groupPanel', directive)
```

Each use of the directive then gets it's own instance. If you want additional info you can try search google for terms like {'angular', 'directive', 'scope', 'controller'] that should put you in the ballpark with the angular documentation.

Also, see the section on "Isolating the scope of a Directive" in this documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive .

Comment: Thanks alot. I spend a lot of time with documents and i didn't realise every directive has own instance with the controller. I will back with full working example soon :)